# How does object[[["key"]]] evaluate to object["key"] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, accessor

Why does javascript evaluate the following as true, given that object `foo` has a valid property `bar`?

```
foo[[[["bar"]]]] === foo["bar"]
```

Based on operator precedence, I would think `foo[[[["bar"]]]]` is trying to access a property with the array `[[["bar"]]]` as the key, but why does that still "flatten down" to the same as `foo["bar"]`?

Colleagues of mine are saying javascript parsers have bracket simplifying which ignores the extra brackets.  I don't think this is true since saving `[[["foo"]]]` to a variable `test` gives the same result:

```
> test = [[["bar"]]]
 [Array[1]]
> foo["bar"] = 5
 5
> foo[test]
 5
```

What aspect of the language or parser is causing this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: It is a duplicate question, but the answers given here are better.

Comment: The "rule" in play lets you do goofy things like this `obj={"undefined":1,"null":2,"[object Object]":3};obj[void(0)];//1 obj[null];//2 obj[{}];//3`

Comment: Can we reverse the "is duplicate of" relation for this question? This question here seems to be the more informed, better presented one of the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript bracket notation accepts an expression, but it always converts the value of that expression to a string. Thus if you pass in an array, it will attempt to convert it to a string. In your case you are passing in an array `[[["bar"]]]`, and `[[["bar"]]].toString() === "bar"`.

If you are wondering why `[[["bar"]]].toString() === "bar"`, it is because when an array `arr` is converted to a string implicitly it is like calling `arr.join(',')`. That is each of its elements are converted to strings and then joined in a comma separated string. When the array only has one element, the string representation of the array is just the string representation of that one element. In your case your array (`[[["bar"]]]`) has one element: `[["bar"]]`.

That array is converted to a string too, and since it is also a one element array, the string representation of it is the string representation of that single element: `["bar"]`.

`["bar"]` is also an array with one element, which is a string, so the string representation of `["bar"]` is just `"bar"`.

What this comes down to is: `[[["bar"]]].toString() === "bar"`

and `foo[[[["bar"]]]]` is the same as `foo[[[["bar"]]].toString()]`.

You would also find that:

```
foo[[[[1]],[2]]] === foo["1,2"]
```

because: `[[[1]],[2]].toString() === "1,2"`.

Comment: Great answer.  I saw in the ES spec that the brackets take an expression, but it's too sneaky at saying that expression gets converted to a string.  That's important to know here, and I like how you started off with that.

Comment: The exception to "always converts the value to a string" is: `foo[Symbol('bar')] != foo[Symbol('bar').toString()]`

Comment: @le_m Yes, of course. I purposefully left out any mention of simples to keep the answer concise. That sentence in my answer is a kind of [lie-to-children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children), but noting that Symbol's behave in the comments is definitely worthwhile, so thank you.

Comment: It is the exception that proves the rule, so to say :)

Answer (score 6):

Let's see how `foo[[[["bar"]]]]` is evaluated, step-by step:

1. The outermost brackets in `foo[...]` denote [a property
   accessor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors). The expression `foo[[[["bar"]]]]` thus translates to
   accessing a property of `foo` with name `[[["bar"]]]`.
2. According to the [ECMA standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type), the abstract operation
   [ToPropertyKey(name)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-topropertykey) is then used to turn the name `[[["bar"]]]`
   into a *property key value*:

   > A *property key value* is either an ECMAScript String value or a Symbol
   >   value.

   The name `[[["bar"]]]` is not of type Symbol and thus converted
   into a string. An array is converted to a string by [joining all its
   string converted values](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.tostring):

   ```
   [[["bar"]]].toString() === "bar"
   ```
3. Which finally means that our property key actually becomes `"bar"`:

   ```
   foo[[[["bar"]]]] === foo[[[["bar"]]].toString()] === foo["bar"]
   ```